# How to retrieve data from sql database with multiple table of the same entitiy

Tags: mysql, sql-server, vb.net

I have sql database of mutiple tables where  one table stores the name of the entity, the other table stores the directory where entity's picture is located,
the behaviour of that specific entity is stored in another table, etc.  I would like to retrieve all the information associated to this specific entity via vb.net and populate all that information on client side fields. I am looking for effient implementation.

Comment: Have you heard of using _joins_ ?

Answer (score 1):

You requirement can be fulfilled by using `JOINS`.
The `MySQL` JOIN clause matches rows in one table with rows in other tables and allows you to query rows that contain columns from both tables.

The syntax of the `MySQL JOIN` clause is as follows:

```
SELECT column_list
FROM t1
INNER JOIN t2 ON join_condition1
INNER JOIN t3 ON join_condition2
...
WHERE where_conditions;
```

[Reference](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-inner-join.aspx)

Comment: That sounds great. What I am looking for is the client side application to make the  query to the sql server database to pull out those information.Thanks!

Comment: @TesfayeAsmera Then your question is way too broad.